# File not added to gallery android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-gallery, android-mediascanner

This app i am making is taking pictures and saving it to sdcard but the images are not being shown in gallery...Is there something wrong with my code

```
public void takepicture(View view){
     try{
           String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
             if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                    //To store public files
                File directory=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        , "Myapp Pictures");                        
                    if(!directory.exists())
                        directory.mkdir();
                // Create an image file name
                    String timeStamp = 
                        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                    String imageFileName = "Img" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
                        file=new File(directory, imageFileName);
                   if(!file.exists())
                       file.createNewFile();                    
             }
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.getCause();   
    }
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    mImageUri=Uri.fromFile(file);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actioncode);          
    }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {                             
            if(requestCode == actioncode){                  
                    if((file.length())==0){
                        file.delete();
                    }                   
            try{
                if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){ 


                         Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                         imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);   
                    }

                    galleryAddPic(file.toString()); 
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.getCause();
            }
        }
    }
```

The image is being shown in the imageview as well as saved to the desired directory but now shown in gallery
And finally this is the code for adding to gallery

```
public void galleryAddPic(String file) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(file);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

Comment: find best solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/30095278/3496570

Comment: Must see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31243659/1925394

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void galleryAddPic(String file) {
    File f = new File(file);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,contentUri);
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```