# How to see camera app take photo asynchronous in the gallery

Tags: android

I am working on a basic camera app. I can take a photo, and I can see it in my app. But I want to see my photo in gallery asynchronous. When restart the phone, I can see my photo in the gallery.

Sample code.

```
public class PhotosActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final int REQUEST_CODE   = 100;

    private Button fotobutton;
    private ImageView foto_image;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "OlkunMustafa";
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    private Uri fileUri;
    // Directory name to store captured images and videos

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photos_activity,container,false);
        fotobutton          = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fotobutton);
        foto_image          = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.foto_image);

        fotobutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if( v == fotobutton) {
            Intent photo_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            fileUri = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            photo_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            startActivityForResult(photo_intent,100);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);
            foto_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri contentUri = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
    }

    private static Uri getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } 
        else {
            return null;
        }

        return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by see my photo in gallery asynchronous? Kindly elaborate more?

Comment: @AndroidWarrior my app take a photo. And this photo save external storage, but I cant see this photo in gallery.

Answer (score 5):

> You need to call a broadcast to tell Android OS that you have added an Image

**First Method**

```
    private void galleryAddPic() 
    {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
       {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
       }
       else
       {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
       }
    }
```

**Second Method**

Or Call

```
ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES))));
```

Also have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722494/3496570)

you can use this method to store image file on media store provider:

```
public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

[**And ScanListener**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30078572/3496570)

**[You can directly save image to Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722494/3496570)**

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this logic :

```
private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;    
private Uri imageUri;

public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```