# Deleted file resurrects after ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE intent

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-file, android-mediascanner

I have to delete an image in my application.
When I use `File.delete` method (returns true, mean successfully deleted), file is deleted on file system, but it's visible in gallery. To delete it from gallery I use sending of `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` intent or calling `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile`.

After that the strange thing happens: deleted file resurrects and returns in `File.listFiles` method.

How do I delete the file both from FileSystem and Gallery?

Comment: You have to send a broadcast to Android OS. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30095278/3496570

Answer (score 3):

Delete it from database:

```
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentResolver;

// if you calling this method from an Activity pass context parameter as this
public void deleteFromDatabase(Context context, File file)
{
    Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external");
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    int result = resolver.delete(contentUri, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[]{file.getPath()});
    if(result > 0){
        // success
    } else {
        // fail or item not exists in database
    }
}
```